# Hole in Built In Microwave Casing

Tags: microwave-oven

There is a 1/2”x1” hole in the top of over the stove microwave casing (metal box that supports microwave oven) where it attaches to cabinet. It is towards the middle away from the mounting holes. Will this affect functionality in any way?

This is for Frigidaire Model LFMV1846VF

[image]

Comment: We're going to need a much better description or (ideally) a photo. Appliances often have stamped openings that are not only not a concern, they serve some purpose.

Comment: At least revise to post a model number so we can seek product images.

Comment: Is this a new microwave? If so, return it. You don't know what might have been damaged inside.

Comment: That looks like somebody hit it with a [pickaxe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickaxe). Not normal, return it.

Comment: The hole in the metal likely doesn't matter but if something inside is damaged, like the wiring, you could have a fire.  Not worth the risk if you can return it.

Comment: `Will this affect functionality in any way?` ... that cannot be answered here ... a physical examination is required

Comment: Because there might be damage inside, a physical exam must include areas underneath the new hole and inside the microwave case.

Answer (score 2):

If the hole is just in the outer shell it will not stop the microwave from functioning.

I would urge caution as now the microwave radiation can leak out. Oh my I used the radiation word.

A light bulb radiates light , the radiation from a microwave is similar to radio waves that are all around us but the microwave ovens are normally between 1.3-2.5Ghz this energy travels in a straight line a pice of metal can be placed over the hole to make sure nothing gets out that could be a fire hazard or affect a pace maker or even damage other electronic devices. The last possibility is getting hit in an eye it would start cooking the eye just like an egg, so it is not safe to use a microwave with a hole in the case for these reasons. covering the hole with metal will eliminate the risks described.

Comment: there is no radiation in that part of the microwave. if there were, it would instantly fry the control circuitry's PCB traces as the waves bounced around inside the metal cabinet. The inner chamber where the food goes is the faraday cage that contains the radiation. The outer cabinet is merely structural/cosmetic. If there's a hole in the inner wall, it's very dangerous, but it should kill itself in moments should that happen. The really bad place to get a hole is the door, since that won't fry the DC controller and will spit out radiation for the duration of the cycle.

Comment: Dan and this is why we have to check them at the hospital not only in front but around the door and any openings I agree if the radiation hits the board there would be arcs and sparks but in the last year 2 units have had to be removed for leakage.